# clinicaltables hcpcs API not working on prod server

Tags: curl, timeout

clinicaltables hcpcs API V3 returns timeout

I am using clinicaltables hcpcs API ('https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/api/hcpcs/v3/search?terms=test')

I am calling it with curl from my php code.

It's working fine on my local environment, my dev server, but when I moved to production server, It keeps giving me a timeout reponse.

I tried to call it with curl directly from ssh terminal, it give me this:

curl -v "https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/api/hcpcs/v3/search?terms=air"

- Trying 130.14.65.58:443...
- Trying 2607:f220:41e:7065::58:443...
- Immediate connect fail for 2607:f220:41e:7065::58: Network is unreachable
- connect to 130.14.65.58 port 443 failed: Connection timed out
- Failed to connect to clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov port 443 after 130235 ms: Connection timed out
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (28) Failed to connect to clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov port 443 after 130235 ms: Connection timed out